# python decimal precision and django DecimalField

Tags: python, django, floating-point, decimal, rounding

Why I get wrong precision here? I've asked 3 decimal digits after the floaing point.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> from decimal import getcontext

>>> getcontext().prec = 3
>>> Decimal(1.111) + Decimal(2.222)
Decimal('3.33') # Why not 3.333?
```

And second question, for django `DecimalField`, I define my field like this:

```
value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
```

does it gives the same result as setting

```
getcontext().prec = 3
```

for Decimal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The `prec` setting acts as `max_digits` setting so if you try to add together decimals of 200.222 and 300.333, you'll see the problem right away. To get exactly 3 decimal places, you can use the `round()` function as such `round(Decimal(123.3334343), 3)`.
2. That question is actually answered in the first part, but just to clarify:
   `max_digits` sets how many digits you can have in total both before and after the comma.
   `decimal_places` specifies how many decimal places are stored.
   Thus the short answer is no: `getcontext().prec = 3` != `decimal_places=3`.

Comment: So max_digits is like getcontext().prec? If so, how can I control decimal places (number of digits after the comma), with the decimal module? i.e what django does to ensure decimal_places?

Comment: @user3599803 I checked the source code and Django (1.9) uses `django.db.backends.utils.format_number` function with a definition of `format_number(value, max_digits, decimal_places)`, but that returns a string since I THINK (not a fact, an opinion. If you look it up, let me know) that decimal is stored as a string in the database.

Comment: Actually in my db - MySQL, the decimals are stored as DECIMAL(10, 3) datatype. So not a string here at least.. Anyway, I still look how to configure the Decimal object decimal_places. If there's a way of course

Comment: @user3599803 Well, you can directly make Decimals from strings (`Decimal("1.123")` works) so if you want to, you can still use the Django util function for that. But it just seems a bit of an overkill, I'd go with `round()`.

Comment: As I know round is a not best choice for Decimal, better to use quantize https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize